# What SQL Server role do you pick for a normal user for ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I used Integrated Security for a database connection for the first time for a website. The website pool uses Network Service as a user. I added Network Service as a SQL Server user mapped to public, then allowed it access to my database as `websiteuser`. There are many aspnet_... roles to choose from. Any links out there that explains which ones to use? Do I just check them all since there's only one login coming from the website?

Answer (score 3):

see [How To: Use Forms Authentication with SQL Server in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx#paght000014_step3), the section titled "*Grant Database Access to Your Web Application Account*". and [here for roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step1), under "*To grant permissions in the database*"